# Show that $X$ is locally compact, and each connected component of $X$ is a point.

Tags: general-topology, compactness, connectedness

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space and suppose that each point has a neighborhood basis of simultaneously open and compact neighborhoods.  Show that $X$ is locally compact, and each connected component of $X$ is a point.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Local compactness of $X$ is trivial. For the second part, note that a compact set in a Hausdorff space is necessarily closed, so each point has a base of clopen nbhds, i.e., nbhds that are simultaneously open and closed. Fix $x\in X$, and show that if $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$, then there are disjoint open sets $U$ and $V$ such that $x\in U$, $y\in V$, and $X=U\cup V$. Conclude that no connected subset of $X$ can contain both $x$ and $y$.